# Node.js server waterfall error TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, waterfall

I am writing a server with two functions, one using the output of another function. When the server runs, it gives an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)' of undefined
    at isAsync (/Users/charles/Documents/Router/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:228:32)
    at wrapAsync (/Users/charles/Documents/Router/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:232:12)
    at nextTask (/Users/charles/Documents/Router/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5308:20)
    at Object.waterfall (/Users/charles/Documents/Router/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5320:5)
    at /Users/charles/Documents/Router/routes/yelp.js:46:15
    at /Users/charles/Documents/Router/node_modules/mongojs/lib/cursor.js:59:24
    at handleCallback (/Users/charles/Documents/Router/node_modules/mongojs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:120:56)
    at /Users/charles/Documents/Router/node_modules/mongojs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:683:5
    at handleCallback (/Users/charles/Documents/Router/node_modules/mongojs/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:171:5)
    at setCursorDeadAndNotified (/Users/charles/Documents/Router/node_modules/mongojs/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:505:3)
```

The code is

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const request = require('request-promise-lite');
const async = require('async');

router.get('/yelp', function(req, res, next) {
  db.input.find({}, {
      term: 1,
      location: 1,
      _id: 0
    })
    .limit(1).sort({
      $natural: -1
    }, function(err, input) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err)
      }

      console.log(input);
      async.waterfall([yelpSearch(input[0]), googleSearch],
        function sendJson(err, restaurants) {
          console.log("waterfall starting");
          if (err) res.send(err);
          res.json(restaurants);
        })
    })
});

// Yelp API call
const yelpSearch = function(input, cb) {
  const client = yelp.client(apiKey);
  client.search(input)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.jsonBody.businesses);
      cb(null, response.jsonBody.businesses);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
}

// Google API call
const googleSearch = function(restaurants, cb) {
  console.log("google starts")
  var apiKey = google_apiKey;
  var cseKey = cseID;
  restaurants.forEach(function(restaurant) {
    var keyWord = restaurant.name + restaurant.city + restaurant.state;

    var googleURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=" + apiKey +
      "q=" + keyWord +
      "&searchType=image" +
      "&cx" + cseKey +
      "&count=5" +
      "&safe=medium";

    var imageURLs = [];
    request.get(googleURL, {
      json: true,
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'thaorell'
      }
    }).then(function(response) {
      response.items.forEach(function(item) {
        imageURLs.append(item.link)
      });

      restaurant.append(imageURLs);
      console.log(imageURLs);
    })
  })
  cb(null, restaurants)
};
```

Does anyone have any experience in this? The error is on the line with: `async.waterfall([yelpSearch(input[0]), googleSearch]`. I am using Yelp API to search for restaurants then for each restaurant, I would like to fetch the Google Search for images of that restaurant.

Comment: What line of your code does that error occur at?

Comment: Are you missing an import for async?  https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html

Comment: @CertainPerformance: I edited it in the question. It occurred at async.waterfall()

Comment: @Gerik: no I didn't

Comment: Hm, it's saying async is not defined and the reason why it wouldn't be defined is because it hasn't been imported, created, or referenced properly.  Can you show us how it's being imported/included?  I don't see it in the code above.

Comment: @Gerik just added above

Comment: My guess is it fails at client.search inside yelpSearch()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you are passing arguments to the first function in the waterfall wrongly, it should be:

```
async.waterfall([
    async.constant(input[0]),
    yelpSearch,
    googleSearch
], function sendJson(err, restaurants) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: That made it. do you know why I couldn't parse the input directly into the function?

Answer (score 1):

Both `yelpSearch` and `googleSearch` are *const*s; they doesn't get hoisted. So, at the time you call `async.waterfall([yelpSearch(input[0]), googleSearch],`, the functions does not exist yet, so it fails. Declare them above `router.get` instead (or change them to hoisted function declarations).

Comment: It doesn't work. Also, I think it fails inside yelpSeach()